# Find (.find()) element based on data attribute using wildcard in jQuery

Tags: jquery, filter, find

Good day!

I wasn't able to find the answer I was looking for here because it seems to be a little more precise. What I'm looking for is a way to find an element based on a data attribute where the value starts with a specific string.

In other words, I want these two to be selected:

```
<a class="button" href="#" data-action="view" ...>
<a class="button" href="#" data-action="view-default" ...>
```

I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
$(this).find('.button[data-action^="view"]')
```

It seems like jQuery is not able to filter in a find query...

Comment: Your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/ekd0wq0f/ ... I guess the problem is what are you targeting with `$(this)`

Comment: Ya, the question is to what refer `this` in your code???

Comment: Howcome this works fine then? `$(this).find('.button[data-action="view"]')` (without the `^`)...

Comment: Nevermind, my .js file was cached with old code in it. Sorry for disturbing you guys :)

Comment: Please request the deletion of this question then

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter instead of find and can use data like this

```js
$(function() {    
    $('.button').filter(function(){
      
        return $(this).data("action")  == 'view' }).css({background:'red'
                                                         
    });  
});
```